# How can I use my cell value in A1 and write this value into another vba code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Input Box:

```
Sub Insert()
Dim myValue As Variant
myValue = InputBox("Need Input")
Range("A1").Value = myValue
End Sub
```

Now I want to use the value in A1 and insert this into another vba code called `Sub pr()`. It is in the same worksheet and table.

It should replace `"www.google.com"` for the input in A1.

```
Set Explorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Explorer.Navigate "www.google.com"
```

When I use `Sub Insert()` again, it should replace it again.

How can I use my value from A1 and write it into vba code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By supposing that the the url you want is in the range("A1") from the first sheet :

```
Sub pr()

Set Explorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Dim url As String
url = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A1").Value
Explorer.Navigate url

End Sub
```

If this is the same sheet you can also use :

```
Sub pr()

Set Explorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Dim url As String
url = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
Explorer.Navigate url

End Sub
```